# Can I invoke a pre-formatter when opening a file in pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

I hate black with a passion, and I want to reformat the code so that it doesn't look awful while I am working on it. To do so, I need to invoke my own formatter that undoes black formatting when I open a file, and let black digest it when I commit it.

Is it possible to do so in pycharm? I know that plain vim has such functionality but I can't seem to find it in pycharm.

Comment: So your codebase requires 'black', but you prefer to develop with 'yours', and you'd prefer to run 'yours' whenever you open a file, then run 'black' so you can commit? What is 'yours' and how do you currently call 'yours'? Are you doing something via the command line? Is it through PyCharm? How do you call 'black'? Are you opposed to you using a hotkey to call 'yours' opposed to automatically? (I can foresee a number of issue with it automatically doing it)

Comment: @nanotek black is called by pre-commit. yours is something I will develop, and will be invoked via the command line to reformat the code the way I want. I want pycharm to invoke that program before opening the file, sort of like autocommand in vim